# Add the next 20 elements in CollectionView every time scrolling on collection view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

My List  **MyWordsList**  has 10000 elements. I am Trying to add the next 100 elements in collectionview every time I scoll down.

Here is my code c#:

```
   public MainPage()
        {


Var MyWordsList  =  await mywordsdatabase.GetWords();
 WordSList.ItemsSource =MyWordsList.Take(100); // start with 100 elemets in the list;

 WordSList.RemainingItemsThreshold = 5;
 WordSList.RemainingItemsThresholdReached += WordSList_RemainingItemsThresholdReached;

        }       


        private void WordSList_RemainingItemsThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Load More Data Here when scroll down
            // Take the next 100 elements 
            // if all the elements are added do not add 


        }
```

Here is Xaml code :

```
<CollectionView x:Name="WordSList" ItemsLayout="Vertical"    >
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
         <DataTemplate>

              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                   <Label TextColor="#7D7D7D" Text="{Binding Word1}"  FontSize="15" />
                   <Label TextColor="Black" Text=" - "  FontSize="15" />
                   <Label TextColor="#0F9D58" Text="{Binding Word2}"  FontSize="15" />
                    </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>

     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do this you are making a local variable that only exists in the method that contains it.

```
Var MyWordsList  =  await mywordsdatabase.GetWords();
```

because you want to use this data later, you need to make it a **class** variable.  You also need a variable to store your data source in

```
List<MyClass> MyWordsList;
ObservableCollection<MyClass> datasource;
int ndx = 100;

public MainPage()
{
   MyWordsList  =  await mywordsdatabase.GetWords();
   WordSList.ItemsSource = datasource = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(MyWordsList.Take(ndx));

   ...
   
}
```

then

```
private void WordSList_RemainingItemsThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    datasource.AddRange(MyWordsList.Skip(ndx).Take(100));
    ndx += 100;
}
```

Comment: I am trying this

Comment: I have an Error when Adding item to datasource at this line ( 
 datasource.AddRange(MyWordsList.Skip(ndx).Take(100));  )  : 'ObservableCollection<MyWords>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no accessible extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'ObservableCollection<MyWords>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Use ObservableRangeCollection instead - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.communitytoolkit.objectmodel.observablerangecollection-1?view=xamarin-community-toolkit-sdk

Comment: I have this error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ObservableRangeCollection<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I cannot load the library. Even when doing : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<MyClass>

Comment: did you add the Xamarin.Community.Toolkit nuget package?

Comment: I cannot use it : Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.Forms from 5.0.0.2083 to 5.0.0.2012. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 LeafWords -> Xamarin.CommunityToolkit 1.3.0-pre1 -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 5.0.0.2083)

Comment: Can you please explain this : WordSList.ItemsSource= datasource = new ObservableCollection<MyWords>(MyWordsList.Take(InitDataNulber));  why do I need  ObservableCollection while I can simply do  WordSList.ItemsSource =MyWordsList.Take(ndx);  and put my   List<MyWords> MyWordsList; as a global variable ?

Comment: An `ObservableCollection` is required if you want the UI to be updated when additional items are added to the list.

Comment: This is not enough to refresh my list everytimes I add items ?   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                MyWordsList.AddRange(MyWordsList.Skip(ndxData).Take(InitDataNulber));
                WordSList.ItemsSource = MyWordsList;
                ndxData += InitDataNulber;
            });

Comment: that is completely reassigning your ItemsSource every time, which is expensive, particularly for 1000s of rows, and really defeats the purpose of incremental load.  Your logic is also using `MyWordsList` as both the source and target, which will not work

Comment: I see. I am trying to implement ObservableRangeCollection

Comment: Thanks very much. Please do I handle ObservableRangeCollection when I delete or Add item. I need to reassig all the list or is there a where to call  await mywordsdatabase.GetWords(); more efficiency

Comment: just use the `Add` and `Remove` methods

Comment: I have succees to do the Add and Remove but   how to do update please.  I have tried this  
                        var item = datasource.FirstOrDefault(w => w.ID == mywordinfos.ID);
                        if (item != null)
                        {
                            item = mywordinfos;
                        }

Comment: if you mean updating the properties of an object already in the list, just find it in the list and update it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your intention here regarding the 10000 items. if you are fine to load them all at once

```
MyWordsList  =  await mywordsdatabase.GetWords();
```

Then you don't need the rest of code as CollectView supports virtualization through the underline control. You can feed the whole collection and it will dynamically allocate/deallocate the item UI element as needed efficiently.

If loading 10000 items from database takes too long, that is where you need to mess around with _RemainingItemsThreshold etc. First the database interface needs to be modified to be able to return only segment of items e.g. `mywordsdatabase.GetWords(startIndex, count);`Then it is probably a good idea to refer some of infinite scrolling implementation:

https://doumer.me/infinite-scroll-with-the-xamarin-forms-collection-view/

Comment: Its can support till 500000 items ?

Comment: no your await mywordsdatabase.GetWords(); will blow off. Are you implementing IEnumerable<> or IQueryable<> in the GetWords method and plan to use defer execution? if so you want to return the object directly without await, and only await on items retrieval. e.g. await MyWordsList .skip(100).take(100).ToListAsync()

Comment: It's a IQueryable